# How to order select with dynamic

Tags: java, oracle

I have function in oracle like this

```
FUNCTION myFunc(p_order_col    IN VARCHAR2 default 'city')
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
    v_result          SYS_REFCURSOR;
begin

    open v_result for  select m.abrv_name AS abrv_name,
               m.full_name AS merchant_name,
               m.city AS city,
               m.phone AS phone
    from myTable m
    where m.full_name=SomeCondition
    order by CASE WHEN p_order_col = 'city' then ff.city end,
               CASE WHEN p_order_col = 'abrv_name' then m.abrv_name end,
               CASE WHEN p_order_col = 'phone' then  m.phone end;

    return v_result;

end myFunc;
```

i am passing `p_order_col` parameter from java, but i am getting ordered data, even withought passing parameter i am not getting data with order by default `city` param

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're getting? For afar the code looks right

Comment: when i am calling without passing  ` p_order_col `  parameter it must be returned data with order city but i am getting cities like : 'Rustavi', 'Tbilisi','Tbilisi','Rustavi' and so on  P.S It is my county's cities

Comment: Can you ad your Java call to the question?

Comment: It is normal call like `callableStmnt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR); callableStmnt.setString(1, 'city'); callableStmnt.execute;` my statement looks like `"{?=call myFunc(?)}"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're slightly confused about how the default value for the optional formal parameter works.

If you call your function as `myFunc()`, with no argument at all, then the default is applied and it acts as if you'd called it as `myFunc('city')`.

But if you call it as `myFunc(null)`, which is what your Java call is doing, the default is not used, and `p_order_col` is actually null.

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#GUID-C1079955-95B2-4D0F-8928-649EDA355461):

> A formal parameter with a default value is called an optional parameter, because its corresponding actual parameter is optional in a subprogram invocation.

That means declaring a default values allows the parameter to be omitted in the call; so both of the calls I showed above are legal.

> Omitting an actual parameter does not make the value of the corresponding formal parameter NULL. To make the value of a formal parameter NULL, specify NULL as either the default value or the actual parameter.

and

> If a subprogram invocation specifies an actual parameter for the formal parameter, then that invocation does not evaluate the default value.

together mean that passing null is not the same as not passing a parameter at all, and since passing null is supplying an actual parameter the default is not used.

You need to handle the possibility of null being passed in explicitly; one way is just to coalesce it in your first order-by clause:

```
order by CASE WHEN COALESCE(p_order_col, 'city') = 'city' then ff.city end,
           CASE WHEN p_order_col = 'abrv_name' then m.abrv_name end,
           CASE WHEN p_order_col = 'phone' then  m.phone end;
```

or perhaps more clearly

```
order by CASE WHEN p_order_col IS NULL OR p_order_col = 'city' then ff.city end,
           CASE WHEN p_order_col = 'abrv_name' then m.abrv_name end,
           CASE WHEN p_order_col = 'phone' then  m.phone end;
```

If you aren't sure you're actually passing null and/or want to also order by city if some other unknown value is passed in, you could approach from a different angle:

```
order by CASE WHEN p_order_col is null
  or p_order_col not in ('abrv_name', 'phone') then m.city end,
```

but then you need to maintain that list too if more valid options are added later.

Yet another approach, if all of the columns are the same data type or can be coerced to be, is to use a single case expression:

```
order by CASE p_order_col WHEN 'abrv_name' then m.abrv_name
  WHEN 'phone' then m.phone ELSE m.city end;
```

with the `else` handling an explicit or default 'city' value, null, or any unexpected value.

---

You *could* change your Java code to call the function with no formal parameter if there is no value to pass:

```
if someVar == null then
{
    callableStmnt = conn.prepareCall("{?=call myFunc()}");
    callableStmnt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR); 
}
else
{
    callableStmnt = conn.prepareCall("{?=call myFunc(?)}");
    callableStmnt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR); 
    callableStmnt.setString(2, someVar);
}
callableStmnt.execute;
```

but that's probably unnecessarily complicating it, and it's better for the function to handle this scenario properly anyway.

Comment: i changed it like you said  `p_order_col IS NULL OR p_order_col = 'city'` but still save result i even declare new variable like `v_order_col       VARCHAR2(40);`  and   `IF (p_order_col IS NULL) THEN
      v_order_col := 'city';
    ELSE
      v_order_col := p_order_col;
    END IF; ` then i wrote    `CASE WHEN v_order_col IS NULL OR v_order_col = 'city' then ff.city end,
           CASE WHEN v_order_col = 'abrv_name' then m.abrv_name end,
           CASE WHEN v_order_col = 'phone' then  m.phone end;`  but still same result data without order

Comment: Please don't dump loads of code into comments. This works for me... what exactly are you passing into `setString()` in this scenario? (This is why adding your Java code to the question would have been helpful).